# WebScraping: Xpath list index out range

Tags: python, list, xpath, web-scraping

When I run the following code I get a list index out of range message:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def get_values():
    print('executing get_values...')
    url = 'https://sports.yahoo.com/nba/stats/weekly/?sortStatId=POINTS_PER_GAME&selectedTable=0'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:100]:
         **FGM = i.xpath('.//td[4]/span/text()')[0] #This runs with no error even though its has similar xpath.**
         print('FGM: ' + FGM)     
         G = i.xpath('.//td[2]/span/text()')[0]
         print(G)

values = get_values()
```

When I run the code I get the following error message:

```
 G=i.xpath('/./td[2]/span/text()')[0]
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I attempted to debug using the following statements.

```
print(parser.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()')) #Returns list['4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '3', '2', '4', '3']
print(parser.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()')[0]) #Returns value = 4
print(len(parser.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()')[0])) # Returns value = 1
```

The output shows the expected values so I'm not sure the reason it is not working. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here you use `//tbody/...` it is however *not* said that for *every* `tbody` there is such subpart.

Comment: @Willem I don't understand the response.  Are you able to provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because there isn't always a `<span>` in the second `<td>`. This should work:

```
def get_values():
    print('executing get_values...')
    url = 'https://sports.yahoo.com/nba/stats/weekly/?sortStatId=POINTS_PER_GAME&selectedTable=0'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:100]:
         FGM = i.xpath('.//td[4]/span/text()')[0] #This runs with no error even though its has similar xpath.**
         print('FGM: ' + FGM)
         G = i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()|.//td[2]/span/text()')[0]  # <--- Changed this
         print(G)

values = get_values()
```

Comment: @ Carlos. Thanks!  You've deepened my understanding.  I have more learning/studying to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A selector that selects items that satisfy a query `//foo/bar/qux` is not the same as writing a query `//foo` then iterate over it, and then expect all these elements to have `./bar/qux`. It is possible that there are a lot of `<foo>`s without a `<bar>`, or `<qux>`.

Here for example, in the source code, we see a `<tr>`:

```
<tr class="Bgc(secondary-enhanced):h" data-reactid="1522">
    <th class="Px(cell-padding-x) Py(cell-padding-y) Bd...>
```

so the `<tr>` does not contain any `<td>`s, but `<th>`s (for a header row).

```
def get_values():
    print('executing get_values...')
    url = 'https://sports.yahoo.com/nba/stats/weekly/?sortStatId=POINTS_PER_GAME&selectedTable=0'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr[td[4]/span and td[2]/span]')[:100]:
         FGM = i.xpath('.//td[4]/span/text()')[0] #This runs with no error even though its has similar xpath.  
         print('FGM: ' + FGM)
         G = i.xpath('.//td[2]/span/text()')[0]
         print(G)
```

Here the last two rows are not included in the result, since these are *not* wrapped in a `<span>` tag, you will thus need to do some extra querying to select the correct rows and extract the correct values.